# Select rows from a dataframe with a vector condition

Tags: r

in the dataframe

```
Version_ID      Development_methodology Version.Type
 75                 Agile                 On-going
 62                 Waterfall             On-going
 63                 Waterfall             On-going
 73                 Waterfall             On-going
 730                Waterfall             On-going
 631                Waterfall             On-going
 61                 Waterfall             On-going
 616                Waterfall             On-going
```

vector of IDs :

```
ind<-c(75,63,73,616)
```

I want to extract the subset whose rows have Version_ID != ind:

```
Version_ID Development_methodology Version.Type
 62                Waterfall         On-going
 730               Waterfall         On-going
 631               Waterfall         On-going
 61                Waterfall         On-going
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the `%in%` operator.

```
df[!df$Version_ID %in% ind, ]
```

See `?"%in%` for more informations